# Closest point property of subset of Hilbert space - what are the conditions for infimum to be finite?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

I am proving the closest point property of a subset of a Hilbert space $H$: given 
$h\in H$ and  a closed, nonempty and convex subset $M\subset H$, consider 
$$d=\inf_{m\in M} \|m-h\|$$
I am trying to show the existence of a sequence $m_{n}\subset M$ such that 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|m_{n}-h\| \to d$.

I'll have no problem doing it, as long as I can prove the existence of a finite infimum. I have read some papers where they say that the infimum exists and is finite, if $M$ is nonempty but they don't say why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have a non-empty set of *nonnegative* quantities ($\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is nonegative).

Comment: Since each term is nonnegative, and at least one term is finite (choose say $m_1$ as any element of $M$, so the distance $||m_1,h||$ is some finite real), and since you're taking an infimum, the infimum will exist. Basically you have a nonempty set of reals bounded below by $0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenters said, the set $\{\|m-h\|:m\in M\}$ has a lower bound, namely $0$. It is also nonempty, since $M$ is nonempty. Therefore, it has a finite infimum.

---

Just for completeness: the rest of the proof involves taking a minimizing sequence $m_n$ as in the question, then observing it has a weakly convergent subsequence, then arguing that the limit of this subsequence is in $M$ and is the closest point to $h$.

Comment: The parallelogram identity comes in handy for obtaining a Cauchy sequence from a minimizing sequence.